# Cakephp application form

Tags: cakephp

I created an application form using `cakephp 2`.

Now I want to know, How can users view only their application details using their user id. Here is the Form controller, the application form and the table for displaying the form

```
//Form controller
    public function index() {
            $this->set('posts', $this->Post->find('all'));
        }
       public function view($id = null) {
            if (!$id) {
                throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
            }

            $post = $this->Post->findById($id);
            if (!$post) {
                throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
            }
            $this->set('post', $post);
        }

        public function add() {
            if ($this->request->is('post')) {
                $this->Post->create();
                if ($this->Post->save($this->request->data)) {
                    $this->Flash->success(__('Your post has been saved.'));
                    return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
                }
                $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to add your post.'));
            }
        }

    //Create form
        echo $this->Form->create('Post');
        echo $this->Form->input('esta',['label'=>'New or Estabilished']);
        echo $this->Form->end('Save Post');

    //Form display

      <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Created</th>
            </tr>
            <?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $post['Post']['id']; ?></td>
                <td>
                    <?php echo $this->Html->link($post['Post']['describe_idea'],
        array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view', $post['Post']['id'])); ?>
                </td>
                <td><?php echo $post['Post']['created']; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php unset($post); ?>
        </table>
```

Comment: add your controller / method code

Answer (score 1):

You said that you are using **cakephp 2.x** please find below code to find record

**for Single Record**

```
$posts = $this->Post->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array('id' => 1)
));
```

**For Multiple record**

```
$posts = $this->Post->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array('id' => 1)
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Add filter in your `action`

**CakePHP 3.x**

```
$posts = $this->Posts->find()
    ->where([
        'Posts.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')
    ]);
```

**CakePHP 2.x**

```
$posts = $this->Posts->find('all', [
     'user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')
]);
```

*Note: Make sure to login user to set `Auth` data.*

Comment: You mean I should add it to the  action as in in the form controller page or on the create page please help me i am new to cakephp, and how can i set the Auth data

Comment: You need to put this in action, wherever you are using `find()` method. In your code  (in question), you can put this in `index()` method to list the posts associated to logged user. For enabling authentication, you must go through the documentation https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html. I will suggest you to complete the tutorial from official documentation first. Also if you have just started learning **CakePHP**, go with **CakePHP 3** instead of **CakePHP 2**.

Comment: Ok thanks the project I am using is built on cakePHP 2 that's why I am using it

Comment: Hi, @Anuj-tbe  added before filter and I add the code to the index but i get an error in the formController Error: Call to a member function where() on null  I added before filter `public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('add');
    }`  this is my index action   `public function index() {
          //  $this->set('posts', $this->Post->find('all'));
            $posts = $this->set('posts', $this->Post->find())->where(['Posts.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')]);
            
        }`

Comment: can you please help me write the code I don't know how to go about it.